# Is there a way to display buttons horizontally in Adaptive Cards?

Tags: botframework

I need to display submit buttons horizontally in an adaptive card.  Is there a way for the same?

I tried for the same using "columnset" but no luck

```
{"type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns":[{
          "type":"Column",
          "width":"auto",
          "items":[{
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Yes",
                    "data": {
                        "feedback" : "Yes"
                        }

                }]}]},
                 {"type":"Column",
          "width":"auto",
                 "items":[{
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Yes",
                    "data": {
                        "feedback" : "Yes"
                        }

                }
            ]
       }] }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

The [AdaptiveCard npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards) package, which Web Chat uses to render cards, uses a host config to define how cards are styled. Web Chat provides its own host config that sets the actionsOrientation value to 'vertical', but you can change this behavior by creating your own host config and setting the actionsOrientation  value to 'horizontal'. Unfortunately, to maintain the rest of Web Chat's card styling, you have to pass the whole host config at the moment, but there is currently an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034) open on GitHub to fix this behavior.

**Custom Host Config**

```
const adaptiveCardHostConfig = {
  "hostCapabilities": {
    "capabilities": null
  },
  "choiceSetInputValueSeparator": ",",
  "supportsInteractivity": true,
  "fontTypes": {
    "default": {
      "fontFamily": "Calibri, sans-serif",
      "fontSizes": {
        "small": 12,
        "default": 14,
        "medium": 17,
        "large": 21,
        "extraLarge": 26
      },
      "fontWeights": {
        "lighter": 200,
        "default": 400,
        "bolder": 600
      }
    },
    "monospace": {
      "fontFamily": "'Courier New', Courier, monospace",
      "fontSizes": {
        "small": 12,
        "default": 14,
        "medium": 17,
        "large": 21,
        "extraLarge": 26
      },
      "fontWeights": {
        "lighter": 200,
        "default": 400,
        "bolder": 600
      }
    }
  },
  "spacing": {
    "small": 3,
    "default": 8,
    "medium": 20,
    "large": 30,
    "extraLarge": 40,
    "padding": 10
  },
  "separator": {
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "lineColor": "#EEEEEE"
  },
  "imageSizes": {
    "small": 40,
    "medium": 80,
    "large": 160
  },
  "containerStyles": {
    "default": {
      "foregroundColors": {
        "default": {
          "default": "#000000",
          "subtle": "#767676",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "dark": {
          "default": "#000000",
          "subtle": "#66000000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "light": {
          "default": "#FFFFFF",
          "subtle": "#33000000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "accent": {
          "default": "#0063B1",
          "subtle": "#0063B1",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "good": {
          "default": "#54a254",
          "subtle": "#DD54a254",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "warning": {
          "default": "#c3ab23",
          "subtle": "#DDc3ab23",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "attention": {
          "default": "#FF0000",
          "subtle": "#DDFF0000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        }
      },
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "emphasis": {
      "foregroundColors": {
        "default": {
          "default": "#000000",
          "subtle": "#767676",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "dark": {
          "default": "#000000",
          "subtle": "#66000000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "light": {
          "default": "#FFFFFF",
          "subtle": "#33000000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "accent": {
          "default": "#2E89FC",
          "subtle": "#882E89FC",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "good": {
          "default": "#54a254",
          "subtle": "#DD54a254",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "warning": {
          "default": "#c3ab23",
          "subtle": "#DDc3ab23",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        },
        "attention": {
          "default": "#FF0000",
          "subtle": "#DDFF0000",
          "highlightColors": {
            "default": "#22000000",
            "subtle": "#11000000"
          }
        }
      },
      "backgroundColor": "#F0F0F0"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "maxActions": 100,
    "spacing": "Default",
    "buttonSpacing": 8,
    "showCard": {
      "actionMode": "Inline",
      "inlineTopMargin": 8,
      "style": "emphasis"
    },
    "preExpandSingleShowCardAction": false,
    "actionsOrientation": "horizontal",
    "actionAlignment": "Stretch",
    "wrap": true
  },
  "adaptiveCard": {
    "allowCustomStyle": false
  },
  "imageSet": {
    "maxImageHeight": 100
  },
  "media": {
    "allowInlinePlayback": true
  },
  "factSet": {
    "title": {
      "size": "Default",
      "color": "Default",
      "isSubtle": false,
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "wrap": true
    },
    "value": {
      "size": "Default",
      "color": "Default",
      "isSubtle": false,
      "weight": "Default",
      "wrap": true
    },
    "spacing": 8
  },
  "cssClassNamePrefix": null,
  "_legacyFontType": {
    "fontFamily": "Segoe UI,Segoe,Segoe WP,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif",
    "fontSizes": {
      "small": 12,
      "default": 14,
      "medium": 17,
      "large": 21,
      "extraLarge": 26
    },
    "fontWeights": {
      "lighter": 200,
      "default": 400,
      "bolder": 600
    }
  }
};
```

**Web Chat**

```
renderWebChat({
  adaptiveCardHostConfig,
  directLine
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

For more details, checkout AdaptiveCard's documentation on [host configs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config).

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there way to have a mix of both horizontal and vertical buttons. I want some cards to be stacked and some to be side by side. Is there a way to do it?