# How add HTML Button in bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I have recently started **.net development** and currently, I am developing a chatbot application in .net using Microsoft bot framework.
Now I have to create **below attached UI on azure Bot framework** but I haven't found any solution for that.
Please help me out to create the attached UI on the Bot framework.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Adaptive Cards to render all kinds of forms and buttons in Chatbot using the Bot framework. The adaptive cards will support different channels like MS Teams, Web Chat, Emulator, etc.

As per your requirement, The adaptive card JSON structure will look like the following way. Also, you can design & Validate your own Adaptive cards using [Adaptive Card Designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "HealthFirst",
        "associatedInputs": "none"
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Credit Card Services"
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Insta Account"
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "WhatsApp Banking"
    }

]
}
```

We can validate the supported channels & versions available for the design of the adaptive card.

[image]

**Sample Output:**

The output UI will change based on the channel that you are going to use for the chatbot development. The given rendered output in MS Team channel ( Check the adaptive card designer URL).

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Adaptive Card samples](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ActivityUpdate.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajeesh, I have tried your JSON  into adaptivecard but its render these buttons  vertically but I want them horizontally

Comment: You are trying which channel like web chat , emulator, etc ?

Comment: I am trying on webchat

Comment: You can use actionsOrientation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config and als check this old answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577757/is-there-a-way-to-display-buttons-horizontally-in-adaptive-cards

Comment: Hoping the above answer is helpful for your requirement then accept answer and it will helpful for others in future.

Comment: Sure Rajeesh I am trying to implement same

Comment: Hi Rajeesh, i have tried a lot but buttons in adaptive card UI  not rendered horizontally on bot framework webchat but its rendered properly on Teams

Comment: how can I set adaptive host config file through code ?

Comment: @पone as per your 'so' question I have given the correct solution and you have accepted the answer as well but in comments you are asking different questions for your additional requirements. Either you can ask these kind of questions separately and maintain the quality of question. So this will helpful for other users in future implementation.

Comment: @पone Go through some of the examples available in google search and I have already given u one example and document information in one of my comment. So you can go through this url as one example : https://www.dancingwithcrm.com/adaptive-cards-and-pcf/. After this also you are facing any issue then you can ask separate question with what you have tried for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adaptive cards. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots) for the same.

[Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io/) are platform-agnostic snippets of UI, authored in JSON, that apps and services can openly exchange.  When delivered to a specific app, the JSON is transformed into native UI that automatically adapts to its surroundings.